# FirestoreRecyclerAdapter onBindViewHolder Not Working properly

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm not sure what am doing wrong but I have a recyclerview populated with firebase firestore using FirestoreRecyclerAdapter. My challenge is that I can add documents and retrieve them to the recyclerview but for some reason, the adapter doesn't set Text.

This is my Adapter

```
public class CategoriesAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<BookCategory, CategoriesAdapter.CategoryHolder> {

public CategoriesAdapter(@NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<BookCategory> options) {
    super(options);
}

@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CategoryHolder categoryHolder, int i, @NonNull BookCategory bookCategory) {
    categoryHolder.txtCategory.setText(bookCategory.getCategory());
    categoryHolder.txtDescription.setText(bookCategory.getDescription());
}

@NonNull
@Override
public CategoryHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_item,
            parent, false);
    return new CategoryHolder(v);
}

class CategoryHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView txtCategory, txtDescription;
    public CategoryHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtCategory = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Category);
        txtDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Description);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you started listening for changes?

Comment: Yes I have. And the recyclerview actually loads the documents but the text on the textviews doesnt appear.

Comment: How to do you check that you actually get the data?

Comment: I can add data to firestore which saves perfectly well. I can also see the info there. The problem is that when I fetch the data to the recyclerview, it just loads blanks.

Comment: If you try to log a value, is something printed out?

Comment: Let me try this and see

Comment: I get the data but still doesnt set text in the texviews

Comment: Please edit your question and show how you check that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the issue. The problem was in the class, I had changed the private variables